# How the mysql email alert when submitting a form?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a form in Adobe Dreamweaver CS4 and I am using PHP and MySql. 
Currently,when user hits the submit button,it captures data in the form and 
submits it to a MySql table.What I would like it to do is to send an email to 
me notifying that a form has been submitted,along with a summary of the data 
entered in the form.So, essentially I want to execute two behaviours on click 
of submit button. 
 I would really appreciate if someone could help me with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the [mail() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mail.php) just before or have the mysql_query call.

Answer (score 0):

Read some examples on how to send mails with PHP and then just iterate through that $_POST array, outputting the key and it's value for every entry.
That way you'll get a true dynamic application which mightn't be pretty but easy and powerful.